# How to make bbPress forum pages use a custom page template

Tags: wordpress, bbpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I created the custom page template bbpress.php so that the forum section of my site will show a sidebar.

I just don't know how to implement it.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a plugin that allowed me to designate what template bbPress uses:

[bbPress WP Tweaks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bbpress-wp-tweaks/)